# How can I use group_by() with my large dataset?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, data.table, large-data

My data set is quite large: 3.2 m obs. of 8 variables of class "data.table" "data.frame"

```
head(groups)
   year                           exporter export_destination_country   product_group export_value location_code partner_code sitc_product_code.x export_destination
1: 2018                             Angola       United Arab Emirates Cheese and curd            0           AGO          ARE                0240                RoW
2: 2018 Congo (Democratic Republic of the)       United Arab Emirates Cheese and curd            0           COD          ARE                0240                RoW
3: 2018                            Comoros       United Arab Emirates Cheese and curd            0           COM          ARE                0240                RoW
4: 2018                          Mauritius       United Arab Emirates Cheese and curd            0           MUS          ARE                0240                RoW
5: 2018                         Seychelles       United Arab Emirates Cheese and curd            0           SYC          ARE                0240                RoW
6: 2018                           Tanzania       United Arab Emirates Cheese and curd            0           TZA          ARE                0240                RoW
```

I have already managed to find a solution that does not overload my R memory, when running my code.
However, surprisingly **dplyr does refuse to conduct group_by in combination with the mutate argument**

```
groups_world <- groups %>%
  group_by(year, exporter, sitc_product_code.x) %>%
  mutate(export_value_w = sum(export_value)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

export_value_w is the same value among all observations.

```
> groups_world
# A tibble: 3,251,385 x 10
    year exporter                           export_destination_country product_group   export_value location_code partner_code sitc_product_code.x export_destination export_value_w
   <dbl> <chr>                              <chr>                      <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>         <chr>        <chr>               <chr>                       <dbl>
 1  2018 Angola                             United Arab Emirates       Cheese and curd            0 AGO           ARE          0240                RoW                 2761298974318
 2  2018 Congo (Democratic Republic of the) United Arab Emirates       Cheese and curd            0 COD           ARE          0240                RoW                 2761298974318
 3  2018 Comoros                            United Arab Emirates       Cheese and curd            0 COM           ARE          0240                RoW                 2761298974318
 4  2018 Mauritius                          United Arab Emirates       Cheese and curd            0 MUS           ARE          0240                RoW                 2761298974318
 5  2018 Seychelles                         United Arab Emirates       Cheese and curd            0 SYC           ARE          0240                RoW                 2761298974318
 6  2018 Tanzania                           United Arab Emirates       Cheese and curd            0 TZA           ARE          0240                RoW                 2761298974318
 7  2018 South Africa                       United Arab Emirates       Cheese and curd         4676 ZAF           ARE          0240                RoW                 2761298974318
 8  2018 Angola                             Argentina                  Cheese and curd            0 AGO           ARG          0240                RoW                 2761298974318
 9  2018 Angola                             Austria                    Cheese and curd            0 AGO           AUT          0240                EU27                2761298974318
10  2018 Congo (Democratic Republic of the) Austria                    Cheese and curd            0 COD           AUT          0240                EU27                2761298974318
# ... with 3,251,375 more rows
```

---

Sample data:

```r
library(data.table)
groups <- setDT(structure(list(year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), exporter = c("Angola", "Congo (Democratic Republic of the)", "Comoros", "Mauritius", "Seychelles", "Tanzania", "South Africa", "Angola", "Angola", "Congo (Democratic Republic of the)"), export_destination_country = c("United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", "United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", "Austria", "Austria" ), product_group = c("Cheese and curd", "Cheese and curd", "Cheese and curd", "Cheese and curd", "Cheese and curd", "Cheese and curd", "Cheese and curd", "Cheese and curd", "Cheese and curd", "Cheese and curd"), export_value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4676, 0, 0, 0), location_code = c("AGO", "COD", "COM", "MUS", "SYC", "TZA", "ZAF", "AGO", "AGO", "COD"), partner_code = c("ARE", "ARE", "ARE", "ARE", "ARE", "ARE", "ARE", "ARG", "AUT", "AUT"), sitc_product_code.x = c("0240", "0240", "0240", "0240", "0240",  "0240", "0240", "0240", "0240", "0240"), export_destination = c("RoW", "RoW", "RoW", "RoW", "RoW", "RoW", "RoW", "RoW", "EU27", "EU27")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: Hi! Could you provide a minimal dataset where you can reproduce this problem?

Comment: use `summarize` instead of `mutate`

Comment: Did you try to use data.table approach?

Comment: @Maël thank you. I think with the minimal dataset the situation shouldn't be a problem, as this code usually works. I think the major issue here is the huge size of the dataset.

Comment: @YuriySaraykin, thank you. Unfortunately, summarize() doesn't work with group_by either. The result is exactly the same number. As the group_by()  argument is not working, mutate() and summarize() take the sum of all observations.

Comment: @zx8754 thank you, could you please elaborate what you mean by data.table approach?

Comment: Try something like this: `groups[, export_value_w := sum(export_value), by = .(year, exporter, sitc_product_code.x) ]`

Comment: Which packages have you loaded? Did you try restarting R and only load the dplyr package?

Comment: What do you mean by dplyr "refuses"? What happens?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your claim that `export_value_w` is uniformly assigned. When I use the sample data visible and run your `groups_world <-` code, I get distinct sums. I second the request for more usable data (`dput(.)` please), but more important, *"dplyr does refuse to conduct"* is vague and unsupported: if you get an error/warning, show it to us. If not, we still need data. Either way, we are "stuck" and this question is not reproducible.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the sample data I was able to scrape.